# NBA Wingspan-To-Height Ratio

Tags: nba

Is there a list where I can see the top NBA wingspan-to-height ratios?

For instance, I read that Dwayne Wade is 6'4" with a 6'11" wingspan. I would like to know other players with wingspans much greater than their height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a list where I can see the top NBA wingspan to height ratios?

The NBA has recorded these stats for the draft combine since 2000. For example, Dwyane Wade's height and wingspan can be found in the [draft combine statistics](https://stats.nba.com/draft/combine-anthro/#!?sort=WINGSPAN&dir=1&SeasonYear=2003-04) for the 2003 draft.

[image]

> I would like to know other players with wingspans much longer than their height.

To see if a player's wingspan is longer than their height, I would do the following:

1. Copy and paste the data into an Excel Spreadsheet (I did not find a way to export the data)
2. Convert the wingspans and heights into inches (eg, 6'3.75" = 75.75 inches)
3. Use [conditional formatting](https://superuser.com/a/695645) to compare the wingspan cells to its respective height cells

If you would like to compute a wingspan-to-height ratio, you may divide the wingspan by the height and come up with another column for the wingspan-to-height ratio.

Comment: Is it possible to sort the statistics by (wingspan minus height) or similar? If not, this doesn't really give a way to find *other* players in this state.

Comment: @PhilipKendall The advanced filters do not cover WINGSPAN or HEIGHT W/O SHOES (eg, WINGSPAN > HEIGHT W/O SHOES). I'm afraid this would be a manual check, unless there is a way to export the data to find such characteristics.